# Add calendar events into template file using PnP Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm adding Calendar items into a template XML file using Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate

```
Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate -Path $templateFilePath -List $listTitle -Query '<View></View>' -Fields $includeFields
```

- My machine Culture is "pt-PT" and Time Zone "GMT Standard Time"
- The Site Collection is "en-US" and Time Zone "Pacific Standard Time"

The event start and end date should be

```
<pnp:DataValue FieldName="EventDate">3/2/2020 9:00 AM</pnp:DataValue>
<pnp:DataValue FieldName="EndDate">5/7/2103 10:00 AM</pnp:DataValue>
```

But is adding like this

```
<pnp:DataValue FieldName="EventDate">02/03/2020 17:00:00</pnp:DataValue>
<pnp:DataValue FieldName="EndDate">07/05/2103 17:00:00</pnp:DataValue>
```

I already set the machine culture and time zone to "en-US" and "Pacific Standard Time" but without luck.

```
Set-TimeZone and Set-Culture
```

What I'm missing here? What I have to set to get the values without the conversion!?

Comment: My guess would be that this is dependent on either the site or your Office365 culture/timezone. Perhaps you could convert the values in the XML in anticipation of  `Add-PnPDataRowsToProvisioningTemplate` converting them, if you can't do anything else.